# Split HDMI output into two adjacent images

Tags: hdmi, video

I am looking for the possibility to produce a two channel video output with a Raspberry Pi 3. That is, a device that splits the HDMI signal, ideally coming from full HD resolution, into two output signals of half width, e.g. 960 x 1080 or 960 x whatever. This can be VGA no problem. To repeat, I produce one regular video output signal, the image is composed of two halves, left and right, and I want the left to go to one monitor and the right to go to another monitor.

So I see there are machines like the [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/), but that box has DisplayPort input and says it requires a Windows box. It also says it appears as a 3840 x 1200 device which probably is not supported on the Pi, and I would need a lower resolution.

Has anyone experience with scenario, is there any machine (as cheap as possible) that can perform such a task and works fine with Raspbian and the Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheapest way to go on my opinion is using displays that has video wall feature built in them. DualHead2Go uses 2 standard resolutions side by side, so if the pi can handle those you're good.
Datapath's X4 (http://www.datapath.co.uk/multi-display-products/datapath-x4) will surely do the trick but it's a bit pricey and you will probably need a windows machine to configure it. 
A normal DA like Mohammad Ali has suggested is not a viable solution because it will duplicate the entire output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://www.amazon.ca/CNE86960-HDMI-Splitter-Amplifier-Display/dp/B0015YRMXI) should work, and even the product you recommended states that Linux is supported in the specifications page. Also In general for future reference HDMI devices aren't usually is specific as the HDMI protocol does not very by OS.

The device you indicated has a maximum resolution of 3840 x 1200, but that isn't the only resolution possible it's just the highest possible which is why it is being advertised. You may manually override the pi's output red resolution by placing the sdcard into a computer then opening a file named `config.txt` and adding the following lines followed by an equal sign and the resolution you want:

```
framebuffer_width   console framebuffer width in pixels. Default is display width minus overscan.
framebuffer_height  console framebuffer height in pixels. Default is display height minus overscan
```